# How does Linq projection work between Extention Method and query expression

Tags: c#, linq

Fiddling around with Linq, and to my surprise I meet the following:

```
var words = new List<string>() {"seven", "ten", "one" ,"five"};

var test1 = words.OrderBy(w => w.Length);
var test2 = words.OrderBy(w => w.Lenght).Select(w => w);
var test3 = from w in words
            orderby w.Length
            select w;
```

And VS debug tells me

```
test1: System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<string>
test2: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>
test3: System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<string>
```

I was expecting same type for `test2` and `test3`, and oh boy!, the compiler, or whatever it is, thinks otherwise.

1. Anyone to shed the light?
2. Also, is there any case I'll prefer `test2` instead of `test1` as long as I'm projecting to the same type? i.e. `Select(w => w)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler omits the call to `Select` when there is no real  transformation in the `select` clause of the query expression. That's why the queries in `test1` and `test3` are equivalent.

My answer is based on this post from Jon Skeet's blog (read the **Query expressions** paragraph):
[LINQ to Objects](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot/)

```
var result = from x in source
                 where x < 4
                 select x;
```

> (...) we’re not actually performing a real transformation. In that case – and so long as there’s something else in the query, in this case our "where" clause – the compiler effectively omits the "select" clause (...)

Regarding the second part of your question, when you invoke `Select` at the end, you'll get an `IEnumerable<T>`, because that's what `Select` returns. `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`, so by making a projection at the end you lose the ability to use members of the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: so the Select in test2 is not necessary? But what got me thinking is why the compiler infer a different type. I thought there must be an explanation for that. Also, it seems the compiler forces you to put Select clause in the query expression, no matter whether there'll be real transformation or not.

Comment: @rm It is a different type simply because `OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` and `Select` returns an `IEnumerable`.  `IOrderedEnumerable` extends `IEnumerable`, so by making a projection at the end you deprive yourself from being able to use members of the `IOrderedEnumerable` interface. And yes, you have to write the `select` clause every time.

Comment: oh yeah. I see. Your comment completes the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @rm I'll add this to the answer.